# Assumption of logistic regression: How to check if the independent variables are linearly related to the log odds (in R)?

Tags: r, logistic, linearity

I want to check if my logistic regression assumes linearity of independent variables and log odds.

I have made the model and tried to construct the linearity of independent variables and log odds, but I am unsure if this was done correctly. Furthermore, I do not know how to interpret this.

I have used this code in R:

```
model <- glm(MetabolicSyndrome ~ LEO + SBD1, data = corrected_data_q3, family = "binomial")
summary(model)

install.packages("car")
library(car)

# Create partial residual plots
partial_resid_plots <- crPlots(model)
```

And I get this output, but I am not sure this is the correct way to check this. And I don't know how to interpret this.

[image]

Comment: This code is not reproducible: where does `model` come from??  What is your model and what method did you use to fit it?

Comment: @whuber, I'm sorry for the slobbyness, i have updated the post. I have performed a logistic regression model with 2 independent variables. To check if this log-model assumes too 'the independent variables are linearly related to the log odds' I have written this code. Now I do not really know if this is correct and how to interpret it.

Comment: Can you say more about what "checking that variables are linearly related to the [the response]" means to you? Are you asking how to perform inference, or are you trying to check assumptions?

Comment: I'm trying to check the 'fourth' assumption (based on this link: https://www.statisticssolutions.com/free-resources/directory-of-statistical-analyses/assumptions-of-logistic-regression/) of logistic regression.

Comment: This is much better handled by postulating a flexible model when effects are not known to be linear and when the sample size supports fitting more than one coefficient for a predictor.  Regression splines are particularly well suited for relaxing the linearity assumption as detailed [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/genreg).  Be sure not to select a model using significance testing or AIC which will invalidate p-values and confidence interval coverage.

Comment: Following up on the comment from @FrankHarrell, there might be a way to model your data that doesn't require that linearity assumption. That depends on further details. In particular, how many cases are there total and in the minority class of your `MetabolicSyndrome` outcome? Might the association of `LEO` with outcome depend on the value of `SBD1`, and vice-versa? Also, one case seems to be an extreme outlier. Please provide that extra information by editing the question, as comments are easy to overlook and can be deleted.